# Why does appending to list change this number?

Tags: python-3.x

I have looked for a solution for this problem for hours and looked through a lot of posts on this site as well, but I could not find a solution. I'm using python 3.9.2

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

raw_data_from_webpage = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes")
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_data_from_webpage.content, 'html5lib')

ec14_content = str(soup.find_all("p"))
ec14_content = re.sub(r"<[^<>]*>", "", ec14_content)
ec14_content = ec14_content.split("\n, ")
ec14_info = "born"
ec14_counter = 0
ec14_answer_list = []
while ec14_counter < len(ec14_content):
    if ec14_info in ec14_content[ec14_counter]:
        ec14_looking = ec14_content[ec14_counter].replace(" c.", " circa").split(". ")
        for i in ec14_looking:
            if ec14_info in i:
                ec14_answer_list.append(i+".")
    ec14_counter += 1
print(ec14_answer_list)
```

print(i) = 287 BC in the seaport city...

print(ec14_answer_list) = \u2009287\xa0BC in the seaport city...

I really hope someone has an answer why this happens...

EDIT:
Added minimal reproducible example.

Regular numbers (like "1906"), and numbers with letters (like "6th") work perfectly, but this problem occurs every time there is a "number" followed by "BC" or "AD" (like "287 BC" or "530 AD")

I am trying to get my program to read a Wikipedia page and find an answer, which it does perfectly, but BC and AD years show up as "\u2009"+number+"\xa0"+BC.

I tried replacing "\u2009" (and "\u2009") with " ", but that didn't do anything...

Comment: If anyone here tries to run this code, it will raise a `NameError` because `i` is not defined. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I am not completely sure since the minimal reproducible example is not given, but your problem could be related to "reference types" because your are talking about in explainable changing of values

Comment: I was hoping it's an easy fix, that's why I only added 3 consecutive lines of code. I wrote a new code that's a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer by messing around with the code and testing a bunch of stuff.

Between "c." and "287" is not a " " but instead a "THSP".
Between "287" and "BC" is also not a " " but instead a "NBSP".
If I copy either the THSP or NBSP they both show up as a " " (space) here, but in python they look like the four letters in a box and are one symbol.

I used the replace function to replace both "THSP" and "NBSP" with " " (space).

```
.replace(" ", " ")
```

Hope it helps someone else as well :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with file encoding in your environment.  \u2009 is the unicode symbol for thin space as shown below:

```
import unicodedata
print(unicodedata.name('\u2009'))
#THIN SPACE
```

Make sure you check the encoding in whatever environment you are using. In my environment with UTF-8, I don't see any problem when using your code:

```
i = "287 BC in the seaport city"
ec14_answer_list = []
ec14_answer_list.append(i+".")
print(ec14_answer_list)
#['287 BC in the seaport city.']
```

The other possibility is that your original string i was encoded improperly. Try to clean up or rewrite i.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added a minimal reproducible example.